# adding the total of each int in a string

Tags: java, string

I have 9 numbers in an string. I would like to add them all together. I am not sure what I am missing I keep getting an error on moons.

What is the correct way to write this?
moons is defined in the Planet class this is the Solar System class: moons holds the number of each planets moons.

Ok i posted full code. in driver i add the planets and how many moons they have. I want to add all the moons together now in the SolarSystem class and System.out.println them

```
package planets;

public class Planet  {


    String name;
    int moons;

    public Planet(String name, int moons)
    {
        this.moons = moons;
        this.name = name;               
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "The Planet " + name  + " Has " + moons + " Moon(s) \r\n ";
    }

}




   package planets;

public class SolarSystem {

    private Planet[]planets;
    private int position = 0;
    Planet[]moons;

 public SolarSystem(int size) {  
     planets = new Planet[size];
 }

public void add(Planet planet) {
    planets[position] = planet;
    position++;

}

public int sum(Planet moons) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < moons(); i++)
        sum += moons[]; 
     }
     return sum;
}

public String toString(){
    String result = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < planets.length; i++){
        result += planets[i].toString(); 

    }
    System.out.println("You Have " + position + " Planets In Your Solar System");

    return result;  

}
}

package planets;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[]args) {

        Planet mercury  = new Planet ("Mercury", 0);

        Planet venus = new Planet ("Venus", 0);

        Planet earth = new Planet ("Earth", 1);

        Planet mars = new Planet ("Mars", 2);

        Planet jupiter = new Planet ("Jupiter", 67);

        Planet saturn = new Planet ("Saturn", 62);

        Planet uranus = new Planet ("Uranus", 27);

        Planet neptune = new Planet ("Neptune", 14);

        Planet pluto = new Planet ("Pluto", 5);

        SolarSystem solarSystem = new SolarSystem(9);       

        solarSystem.add(mercury);
        solarSystem.add(venus);
        solarSystem.add(earth);
        solarSystem.add(mars);
        solarSystem.add(jupiter);
        solarSystem.add(saturn);
        solarSystem.add(uranus);
        solarSystem.add(neptune);
        solarSystem.add(pluto);



        System.out.println(solarSystem);

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you think `sum += moons[];` should do?

Comment: Is moons supposed to be an array?

Comment: `moons` isn't an array.  `[]` doesn't work for it, even if you should actually supply an index value.

Comment: Ok i posted full code. in driver i add the planets and how many moons they have. I want to add all the moons together now in the SolarSystem class and System.out.println them

Comment: Go look at how to declare and work with arrays, that code does not compile.

Comment: The operator `+=` only works on some `Number` types, numeric primitive types, and `String`.

Comment: lol i know the code does not compile thats why im asking for help. its just when I try to add all the int in moons together. I know I am doing it wrong how can I fix it.

Comment: As a general suggestion, it is a good idea to either use an IDE that will tell you immediately when you have written something with incorrect syntax, or to write a little code, compile, test, repeat. It looks like you wrote a fair amount of code without checking whether it worked or even compiled. Once you get to that point it can be difficult to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just leave everything as it is and use this actual working java code for sum

```
public int sum(Planet[] planets) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(Planet planet : planets){
        sum += planet.moons; 
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: thank you. so to print this out I try this
System.out.println("You Have " + position + " Planets In Your Solar System And" + sum + "Moons");
 but it does not work. Why is that?

Comment: Supposing you put that in SolarSystem toString : `System.out.println("You Have " + position + " Planets In Your Solar System And" + this.sum(this.planets) + "Moons")`

Answer (score 1):

use something like below, though I have not tested it.

```
public int sum(Planet[] planets) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(Planet planet : planets)
        sum += planet.moons[]; 
     }
     return sum;
}
```

you should pass an array of objects of type `Planet` and then get the `moons` field from each `Planet` and add it to sum.

As a suggestion, since you are already adding the `Planet` objects to an array in `SolarSystem`, just add a `getPlanets()` method to that class, so that you can get the array of `Planet` objects also from `SolarSystem` class if you need.

```
public Planet[] getPlanets()
{
   return planets;
}
```

also, dont use the function name as `sum` use something like `totalMoons()`.

Comment: That is definitely not Java syntax :-)

Comment: Thank you tons for your help. That makes sense but when I add it Planet planet in gets errors. as well as planet.moons

Comment: @codeNinja yes.. not an actual code.. will make it clear in asnwer

Comment: There is no `foreach` in Java.

Comment: @anonymous jumped the gun with c#:P.. corrected it :)